# How to build .Net Core Application from C# code using "BuildManager"?

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild

I want to build .Net Core 2.1 Console application from C# code. I am using BuildManager to build solution.

```
               using (var buildManager = new BuildManager())
                {
                    var bp = new BuildParameters(projectCollection)
                    {
                        Loggers = new List<ILogger>
                        {
                            logger
                        },
                        OnlyLogCriticalEvents = false,
                        DetailedSummary = true,
                        NodeExeLocation = @"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Professional\\MSBuild\\Current\\Bin\\MSBuild.exe"
                    };

                    var buildRequest = new BuildRequestData(
                        "projectFullPath",
                        globalProperties, null, new[] { "Build" }, null,
                        BuildRequestDataFlags.ReplaceExistingProjectInstance);

                    BuildSubmission submission = null;

                    buildManager.BeginBuild(bp);
                    submission = buildManager.PendBuildRequest(buildRequest);

                    buildResult = submission.Execute();
                    buildManager.EndBuild();
```

I already have set Environment Variables like this:

```
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MSBuildExtensionsPath", globalProperties["MSBuildExtensionsPath"]);
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MSBuildFrameworkToolsPath", globalProperties["MSBuildFrameworkToolsPath"]);
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MSBuildToolsPath32", globalProperties["MSBuildToolsPath32"]);
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MSBuildSDKsPath", globalProperties["MSBuildSDKsPath"]);
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("RoslynTargetsPath", globalProperties["RoslynTargetsPath"]);
```

Where globalProperties:

```
            Path.Combine(programFilesX86, @"Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe"),
            Path.Combine(programFilesX86,
                @"Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"),
            Path.Combine(programFilesX86, @"Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"),
            Path.Combine(programFilesX86, @"Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"),
            Path.Combine(programFilesX86, @"MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"),
            Path.Combine(programFilesX86, @"MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe")
```

And Now I have build error.

```
    Build FAILED.

    MSBUILD : warning MSB4196: The "*.overridetasks" files could not be successfully loaded from their expected location "C:\Learn\NetCoreApplicationTestingBuild\NetCoreApplicationTestingBuild\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1". Default tasks will not be overridden. 
    MSBUILD : warning MSB4010: The "*.tasks" files could not be successfully loaded from their expected location "C:\Learn\NetCoreApplicationTestingBuild\NetCoreApplicationTestingBuild\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1". Default tasks will not be available.
    C:\Learn\NetCoreTestBuild2\NetCoreTestBuild2.sln.metaproj : error MSB4036: The "Message" task was not found. Check the following: 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task is correctly declared with <UsingTask> in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:\Learn\NetCoreApplicationTestingBuild\NetCoreApplicationTestingBuild\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1" directory.

    2 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

Comment: It looks like the error message is telling you where and what to check, have you checked this? The error message reads: `error MSB4036: The "Message" task was not found. Check the following: 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task is correctly declared with <UsingTask> in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:\Learn\NetCoreApplicationTestingBuild\NetCoreApplicationTestingBuild\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1" directory.`

Comment: @JamieTaylor I didn't create any tasks and I don't have any task in my project. My goal it is build .Net Core Application from c# code using Build Manager and when I try to do this I am getting this error. Maybe, Do you know how to build .Net Core from code . I will be very appreciate for any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by installing the 'Microsoft.Build.Runtime' nuget package which resolved the missing *.overridestasks and *.tasks errors